# Is Banach space not a countable union of closed subspaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, banach-spaces

Let $B$ be a Banach space and $\left\{ X_{n}\right\} $ closed subspaces of $B
$ with $X_{n}\neq B$ for any $n\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{2115} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{N}
%EndExpansion
$. Prove that $\underset{n\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{2115} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{N}
%EndExpansion
}{\cup }X_{n}\neq B$.

I have only been able to show that $ X_{n}$ has empty interior, but I have failed to show that $\underset{n\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{2115} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{N}
%EndExpansion
}{\cup }X_{n}\neq B$
I appreciate the attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose to the contrary that $\underset{n\in 
%TCIMACRO{\U{2115} }%
%BeginExpansion
\mathbb{N}
%EndExpansion
}{\cup }X_{n}= B$. Baire says now: there is some $n \in \mathbb N$ such that $X_n$ has a non-empty interior.

Let $x_0 \in X_n^{o}$. Then there is $r>0$ such that

$K:=\{x \in B: ||x-x_0||<r\} \subseteq X_n$

Now let $z \in B$ and $z \ne x_0$ and put $t:=\frac{r}{2 ||x_0-z||}$ and $y:=x_0+t(x_0-z)$. Then

$||x_0-y||=t||x_0-z|| = r/2<r$. Hence $y \in K$ and therefore $y \in X_n$.

Since $X_n$ is a subpace and $x_0 \in X_n$:

$z=x_0+(x_0-y)/t \in X_n$.

We then have $X_n=B$, a contradiction.